# VideoJS override method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video.js

How can I override the method: **buildAndActivateControlBar** of the player VideoJS?

I'm trying with the prototype way but no result...

I want to make a inherited class of VideoJS to override buildAndActivateControlBar method to add some controls in the player, then call the base method buildAndActivateControlBar

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but if you're going to modify things, I'd highly recommend upgrading to the latest version of Video.js, released in January. It was a big rewrite.